# How can I use a template parameter of class to pass as argument of template for my linked list?

Tags: c++, templates, singly-linked-list

I have one class:

```
template <class EventType = SFAEvent>
class SFAEventDispatcher {
    SFALinkedList<SFACallback<EventType> > callbacks[size];

    void dispatch(EventType &e) {
        ...
        SFALinkedList<SFACallback<EventType> >::iterator iter = callbacks[e.type].begin;
        ...
    };

}
```

I'm using a LinkedList with iterator defined as:

```
template <typename Type>
class SFALinkedList {
public: 
    typedef SFALinkedListIterator<SFASinglyElement<Type> > iterator;
}
```

The problem is:

If I use:

```
SFALinkedList<SFACallback<EventType> >::iterator iter;
```

EventType defined in template, don't work, but if I use:

```
SFALinkedList<SFACallback<SFAEvent> >::iterator;
```

SFAEvent being a class, work;

Example of my Linked List:

```
SFALinkedList<float> list;
list.append(1.1);
list.append(2.2);
list.append(3.3);
list.append(4.4);

for(SFALinkedList<float>::iterator inter = list.begin(); inter.hasNext(); inter.next()) {
    //print inter.current(); 
}
```

How can I use EventType defined in template of SFAEventDispatcher class to pass as argument of template for my linked list?

Comment: Please be specific about what "works" and "doesnt work" mean. Also please post the error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EventType` is a template parameter. When you write this:

```
SFALinkedList<SFACallback<EventType> >::iterator iter;
```

The compiler does not know what is `::iterator`: is it a type, or a variable ? By default, it is interpreted as a variable. You have to help it by specifying `typename` to indicate a type:

```
typename SFALinkedList<SFACallback<EventType> >::iterator iter;
//^^^^^^                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
//  |                                              |
//  +----------------------------------------------+
```

For more information, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

*As usual, gcc is a disaster on the error-reporting side...*

[Live example here](http://codepad.org/ZgZBkpza).

Answer (score 1):

`EventType` is a *formal* parameter of your template so there's no meaning when you instantiate your template like this (as long as there's no actual class `EventType`)

```
SFALinkedList<SFACallback<EventType> >::iterator iter;
```

You should pass an *actual* parameter to instantiate the template e.g.,

```
SFALinkedList<SFACallback<SFAEvent> >::iterator iter;
```

Also, I believe if you have an actual class `EventType` compiler wouldn't allow to use it as a  formal parameter.

Comment: @wellfer123 No, If you have a class named `EventType`, you can still have template parameters named `EventType`. Names are 'scoped'.

Comment: Also, I believe if you have an actual class EventType compiler wouldn't allow to use it as a formal parameter.
(I will try if it work)
Thanks